# Speed up FireFox when using TOR

Tags: firefox, speed, privacy, tor

After reading [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1820/surfing-the-web-anonymously) about surfing the web anonymously, I tried TOR with Firefox and it seems to be changing the original IP, but Firefox is really slow!

I have a good network speed, and I've never waited more than 3 seconds for a page to load, but with TOR activated I feel that for Google to load it's like eternity.

So, is there any configuration or workaround concerned TOR to speed up things a little?

***[EDIT]***

since it has to be like that, are there any alternatives to TOR out there?

Comment: They mentioned something called itshidden on torrentfreak that may be worth a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately because of the way tor works by routing your traffic through multiple nodes in the tor network your speed is dependant on the slowest point in its journey.

Answer (score 4):

I forget the exact term in TOR, but is about changing you identity(You have that on right click menu). This means that TOR will connect you to a different server, which can have a better speed or may be closer to your location.

Do that several times, until you find a faster server to connect at. Ofcorse, you also can choose what server to use.

maybe offtopic, but is nice to know: In case you didn't hear about [Pirate Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_Party), they are already in UE parliament and they fight for privacy on the internet. [read about Pirate Party new TOR nodes in order to help free speech in Iran](http://www.zeropaid.com/news/86458/will-pirate-party-tor-nodes-be-used-for-more-than-iranian-free-speech/)

Good luck

Comment: it´s called ´Use a New Identity´ you can access through right click or double click on the Tor Icon.

Answer (score 2):

Col is right. I would try a VPN service instead, such as hotspot shield

Comment: If the need for Tor is anonymity then a VPN may not help the same way. You can be traced by to the server the VPN is on and that server's administrators will probably be able to identify you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try DuckDuckGo as your search engine which now operates a TOR exit enclave which should speed up you results through TOR. Read here http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2010/08/duckduckgo-now-operates-a-tor-exit-enclave.html

Answer (score 0):

> I tried TOR with Firefox and it seems
>   to be changing the original IP

that is the whole idea behind using a web proxy.

> but Firefox is really slow!

and that is the disadvantage of using a web proxy.

as they say: you can't have your cake and eat it. :)

Comment: hihiii, right! so any alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

TOR is really slow when used alone... Try searching the web for "Gpass" and use it along with TOR. It will speed up things ... I haven't memorized the interface of gpass but then browse the settings, and just select tor (make sure TOR is running already) or select socks proxy and enter 127.0.0.1 in the proxy and 9050 in the port. change the proxy settings of firefox to 127.0.0.1 port 8000. A little thanks would be appreciated.

Comment: Please describe how Gpass is supposed to work with Tor. Wikipedia knows nothing about this software.