# Does disabling third-party cookies really do anything helpful?

Tags: cookies

I've been reading a lot about the "evils" of third-party cookies a lot recently. I disabled them and haven't noticed many changes.

I have an adblocker, and google is told to not use my information in ads (so when I am logged into my google account, I just see generic ads instead of targeted ones).

I've also read that google uses your browsing history, etc to give you better search results. When I click the button in chrome that says "The following cookies have been blocked on this page", I see a google cookie. That means that google *isn't able to get as much info on me*.

So, because I have ad tracking turned off, does having third-party cookies disabled do anything?

Comment: You've only opted out of google's tracking . . . Different banner ad networks could have third-party cookies, as could sites that use third-party sites to gather stats (e.g. sites like google analytics), various page widgets (e.g. discussion threads that aren't hosted locally), etc.

Comment: Related: [Surfing the web anonymously](http://superuser.com/q/1820/24537)

Comment: @ernie Alright, cool. Thanks for posting that. If you want to post it as a question I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only opted out of google's tracking . . . Different banner ad networks could have third-party cookies, as could sites that use third-party sites to gather stats (e.g. sites like google analytics), various page widgets (e.g. discussion threads that aren't hosted locally), etc.