# What traces do I leave when downloading from internet?

Tags: internet

When I download a file from internet, either via HTTP or FTP, what is recorded on the other side? How much details is it possible to record, how many clues do I leave behind?

This question is not about being anonymous on internet but rather curiosity on what your computer transmits when establishing a connection to another server. What is in the packets?

Comment: Any Information required to send you the file or information the server recorded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Surfing the web anonymously](http://superuser.com/questions/1820/surfing-the-web-anonymously)

Comment: @allquixotic it´s not about surfing the web anonymously. I´m curious of what metadata is transmitted

Answer (score 1):

Maybe nothing, if the site keeps no logs.  Right up to, recording every single packet -- not that I know of anyone doing that; an IDS would *look* every packet, but not necessarily record them.

The site would know"

- everything you tell them (username, email, etc.) -- i.e. any form you filled out
- your apparent IP address, or at least the end-point the site is communicating with (think ToR, VPN, etc.)
- anything a 3rd party ad/statistics site might have collected on you (correlation -- by ip, cookie, etc -- with other sites visited, etc.)

For the perpetually paranoid, the question is *what **can't** they know about you?*

Comment: If it's webbrowsing, you give the server a plethora of info, enough to [pretty much uniquely identify you](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)