# What's the easiest way to detect and delete "Flash Cookies"

Tags: security, flash, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automatically remove Flash history/privacy trail? Or stop Flash from storing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-stori)

This [article](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2009/08/you-deleted-your-cookies-think-again/) has some disturbing information on how "Flash Cookies" even traditional cookies that you think you've deleted. Does anyone have a step-by-step how-to to detect "Flash cookies" and also how to delete them?

Comment: Read this? http://superuser.com/questions/1627/

Comment: +1 nope. I obviously haven't. but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Adobe Flash Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html)

[image]

Simplest Way for firefox : 
 [BetterPrivacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6623) add-on for firefox .

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has a [Flash Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html) which you can use to set up your privacy settings for Flash.  You can also delete flash cookies from the UI (use the [Web Storage Setttings tab](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html)).