# Flash cookie editor

Tags: flash, cookies

Is there a flash cookie editor for Windows? 
Possibly something that can view/edit/delete all the flash cookies on my machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to detect and delete "Flash Cookies"](http://superuser.com/questions/21061/whats-the-easiest-way-to-detect-and-delete-flash-cookies)

Comment: Also, [related](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Getting-a-grip-on-Flash-cookies-Adobe-publishes-Flash-10-3-1242645.html). Perhaps wait another few weeks. [Tech Note how to manage "Flash cookies" by Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/526/52697ee8.html).

Comment: If you want a browser addon, you should specify what browser you're using.

Comment: I am aware some of the methods for deleting flash cookies including the Global Settings Storage panel but have not seen an app that can view/edit cookies.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Flash cookies are stored in binary format, not text files like normal cookies, so you’ll have to find / wait for someone to write a program that can read/write them (which may not happen if the format is proprietary, and would thus take longer since someone would have to reverse-engineer it).

That said, Nirsoft’s [FlashCookiesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/flash_cookies_view.html) lets you at least view and delete Flash cookies. Some cookies cannot be read, but FlashCookiesView allows you to at least view the cookie’s in a build-in hex-editor.

Answer (score 1):

[Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/help/firefox) can be set to delete flash cookies on close.

Answer (score 0):

If someone like me goes here, there's soleditor to edit flash cookies: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/soleditor/