# A bunch of questions on flash player

Tags: flash-player

1. Whats the difference between adobe flash player activex and adobe flash player plugin?
2. Where is the adobe flash player (include activex and plugin) installed?
3. If I want to view swf file standalone without web browser, how could I do it, do I need to install standalone version?
4. Some swf files have controlbars, the other haven't. How could I add the controlbar to the none ones? Is there any flash player that could always show the controlbar above the movie?

thanks.

Comment: I do not know the rule much.If I asked too much questions(considering 4) in one post,plz let me know,then I could sperated it.thx.

Comment: Spreading would be good or consolidating them if they're all just tiny bits of the same question.

Comment: 5. How to automatically remove Flash history/privacy trail? Or stop Flash from storing it? ;-) (See the long, but detailed, http://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-storing-it if you want to know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The activeX is for Internet Explorer, while the plugin is for Firefox and other browsers.
2. Not sure. From what I see on my system: Partly under %windir%\system32\Macromed\Flash, partly under %userprofile%\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player
3. With [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/), you can play .swf movies. There also exist [stand](http://webtrickz.com/free-standalone-flash-player-to-play-swf-flv-files/) [alone](http://www.globfx.com/products/swfplayer/) [players](http://www.rocketdownload.com/program/standalone-flash-player-98094.html).
4. Don't know. I thought the control bars came with the player, not the .swf. But I could be wrong.
   I do know, When you use one of the media players mentioned in number 3 above, you have the control bars supplied with that particular media player (or use the shortcuts).

Comment: For #4, control bars are not built-in to Flash; most video players make their own. So you wouldn't be able to add a control bar to a player that does not have one.

Comment: for #2 that shouldn't be the plugin/ActiveX itself, just site-specific programs downloaded from sites you visit, and flash cookies.  (mmmm, cookies...)

Comment: for #2 that should be the plugin/Active itself,at least flash10c.ocx insatlled in %windir%\system32\Macromed\Flash in my windows xp,and the install log showed this dir is the main place for the flash player.As the latter one,in my computer its full with the site-specific swf-related files.

Comment: for #3 adobe himself has one standalone flash player called SAFlashPlayer.exe.I could not find the download link in google english and download.com,but find it easily in our download.com equal skycn.com

Comment: for #2: adobe flash player plugin for opera.installed at the installation directory of opear => %opera%\program\plugins