# Firefox addon for anonymous web surfing

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, privacy

I need to switch to anonymous surfing mode for specific sites. Is there a Firefox addon for anonymous web surfing?

Comment: use private browsing !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is [Tor (The Onion Router) network](http://www.torproject.org) something for you? With Tor, you are anonymous for everybody in the network, but it requires to install software on a PC. There some warnings in [the FAQ page](http://www.torproject.org/faq-abuse.html) about the usage of Tor.

[Torbutton](http://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/2275) is an extension that will switch the Tor usage for you.

If you just need the browser not to record usage data (cookies, history, cache), then you can use the Privacy Mode in Firefox.

There's also an extension called [QuickProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1557) that allows you to switch the Proxy status fast. You can use an anonymous proxy somewhere abroad to hide your visits.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your answer, but QuickProxy does not provide a proxy server. So I need further adjustments. Can you propose some proxy servers to fulfill the anonymity in Firefox? (or, does Tor provide proxy servers?)

Comment: I installed Tor and it works fine, but now all my sites, they cannot automatically log me on. I need a better solution.

Comment: if you want to log on, why do you need anonymity? Unless you want to escape an IP block on some site?

Comment: I just need to hide specific sites I visited from the network admin.

Comment: Even Privacy Mode and other built-in "private" modes are not too private when visiting Flash-enabled sites: http://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-storing-it

Comment: mehper: There are lot's of free proxies out there, some are not free. So you have to search for yourself, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [FoxyProxy](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/) add-on which does a great job of switching proxy servers for me.  They have an [additional, subscription-based proxy service](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/proxyservice/), which I've never used, but seems reasonably cheap ($20 for 3 months).

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.5.5 and FoxyProxy Standard does not install. There are complaints about this issue in the review section of https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2464

Comment: I'm on 3.5.3 and I haven't had a problem yet; I guess I won't be upgrading anytime soon....