# Do Chrome and Firefox share a browser cache?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-cache

So I was having a problem with some stuff on SO not working that was similar to [this post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/cannot-load-javascript-file-on-stackoverflow-com) which recommended clearing the browser cache.

Now it wasn't working in both Chrome and Firefox and I had never logged in to SO on FF before today so FF couldn't have cached the file itself.  Tried hitting refresh multiple times and even tried Ctrl-F5 with no luck.

I cleared the browser cache in Chrome only, and after that it started working on both Chrome and FF.  How could clearing the cache of one browser affect the other?

Comment: Had issues on FF today as well, can't figure it out. IE works fine, cleaning FF doesn't help (even its DNS cache via plugin).

Comment: I see this in Windows between Chrome and FF. They do share the cache and I don't know how to to stop it.

Answer (score 7):

The browsers do not share a cache, but plugins might. Like Adobe Flash keeps [cross-browser history and "local shared objects"](https://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-stori), which can be used in a cookie-like way. Clearing a cache in a browser usually does not remove the information stored by such plugin.

Comment: "Like Adobe Flash keeps cross-browser history" sounds like a security issue

Comment: "Like Adobe Flash" sounds like a security issue.

Comment: "LIKE" sounds like a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux they don't share cache, they've different folders. Maybe it's the cache at the web server, this usually happens to me when coding modules for joomla or drupal and some $_SESSION (in php) are still saved and make the website look different on different browsers.

Comment: Server-side sessions like those maintained by `$_SESSION` often rely on cookies, and cookies are not shared across browsers. Hence, each browser would have its own session.