# How to change default directory of flash cookies?

Tags: flash, cookies

Local shared objects, sometimes referred to as "Flash cookies," are data files that can be created on your computer by the sites you visit

Flash cookies are stored in a special directory depending on the operating system on the client machine. For windows:
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\`

How to change it to another directory or drive such as,
`D:\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\`

In TuneUpUtilities, we can change location some of special folder, but only limited for `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: Just in case you want this to block the cookies: see (the old) [How to automatically remove Flash history/privacy trail? Or stop Flash from storing it?](http://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-stor)