# Restrict Firefox to specific sites

Tags: firefox, safe-browsing

There are a few particularly pernicious sites that I actually use who also monitor users activity everywhere online, mostly just Facebook, but every so often I'll log into a Google service.

I'll set up disjoint Firefox profiles for each such site and launch them with aliases or scripts, like `facebook` that accesses facebookcorewwwi.onion, or `google` that connects from tor to a vpn.

Ideally, these special profiles should fail to access sites not critical to their respective sites, i.e. if I click a facebook link to youtube then a tab opens with a 404 message and I manually copy the youtube URL to a Firefox instance with another profile.

Two questions:

- Does Firefox share *any* information between profiles?  Caching, Site data, etc.?
- How would you go about ensuring a profile to *only* works on a specific site?

Any other considerations you can think of?

Comment: This might be a better question for Mozilla support: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/firefox or https://ask.mozilla.org/questions/

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [private browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history) is for?

Comment: I don't know the current state, but Flash data was even shared between browsers [six years ago](http://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-stor). Also, when using IPv6, [make sure you use privacy addressing](http://superuser.com/questions/243669/how-to-avoid-exposing-my-mac-address-when-using-ipv6).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked a Privoxy?  http://www.privoxy.org/  It isn't integrated with Firefox but gives you very fine grained control of what traffic is allowed.

Comment: Answers that are basically a link to a resource are considered low quality, but you have the start of a good answer here. You could talk about proxies in general and offer privoxy as a specific option.

Comment: Regardless of the "quality" you consider the answer, it is an approach that may solve the OP's issue.  The link was provided as it has all of the information you are asking me to elaborate on.  I posted the suggestion because it may be a solution the OP hadn't considered.

Comment: Link-only answers are a problem if the link goes stale. Can you pull out the relevant details from the link to add to your answer? I'm not disagreeing with your answer in general, just that the content is too "light".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.